# install php fork on ubuntu

Tags: php, configuration, fork

I'm trying to use fork in php for first time.
when I use

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // we are the parent
     pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children
} else {
     // we are the child
}
```

(fork example in php.net) I will received following error.

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/fork.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

I think fork is not enable,so I donwload php5 source code and do

```
./configure --enable-pcntl
make
make install
```

but I will get same error too.
where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

execute phpinfo(); and see if pcntl is enabled.

Comment: It's not enable.I done it befor,but I can't find any pcntl word in result.